# Deploy a Wildfly with PostgreSQL driver on Heroku

Tags: postgresql, maven, heroku, wildfly

I attempt to host my application on Heroku, my application uses Wildfly 9.0.1 with PostgreSql driver. I follow a web tutorial, 
but the tutorial only cover the Wildfly by default, at this point, i success deploy and start Wildfly on heroku, with this steps:

on pom.xml:

```
<!-- this plugin install Wildfly on HEROKU -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unpack</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
                                <artifactId>wildfly-dist</artifactId>
                                <version>9.0.1.Final</version>
                                <type>zip</type>
                                <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                                <outputDirectory>target</outputDirectory>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                    <version>9.3-1103-jdbc41</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>

        <!-- tell application uses the above wildfly. -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <outputDirectory>target/wildfly-9.0.1.Final/standalone/deployments</outputDirectory>
                <warName>hktest</warName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Finish, the Heroku needs this line on a Procfile (A Procfile is a mechanism for declaring what commands are run by your application’s).

```
web: target/wildfly-9.0.1.Final/bin/standalone.sh -Djboss.http.port=$PORT -b 0.0.0.0
```

Now, i need to configure a postgreSql Driver and configure a datasource for Wildfly, how i can do this? in the first plugin i put the driver
dependency, in the logs, i see if this airfact is downloaded, but need to install then on Wildfly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to instal the driver, maybe this tutorial usefull:
[Configure wildfly datasource](http://www.radcortez.com/configure-jboss-wildfly-datasource-with-maven/)
Or this:
[This use the Wildfly console to install the driver](http://www.nailedtothex.org/roller/kyle/entry/registering-postgresql-jdbc-driver-datasource)

Comment: It's best to provide the bulk of the answer in your post, and only provide links for reference.  Links can change/go stale, so including the answer directly makes for a better answer for future readers.